# Is Dirichlet's Theorem lenient?

Tags: number-theory

Regarding Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in an arithmetical progression, is it true that for each real number $w$ there exist relatively prime positive integers $a$ and $d$ such that for the sequence whose first term is $a$ and whose constant difference is $d$, the first prime occurring in the sequence
has a subscript (as a term within the arithmetical sequence) greater than $w$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=N!+2$, where $N$ is an integer $\gt |w|+3$, and let $d=1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not exist a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb R$ that is one-to-one with the set of relatively prime integers $(a,d)_w$ such that $f(w)$ = $(a,d)_w$   since the count $w$ of $\mathbb R$ is strictly greater than that of the count $n$ of $\mathbb Z$, since by definition of one-to-one there must exist exactly 1 $(a,d)_n$ $\forall$ $w\in \mathbb R$, $\forall$ $n\in \mathbb Z$, but there are elements $w\in\mathbb R$ which do not have a corresponding $(a,d)_n$ (by Cantor's cardinality proof), since the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, $x$  is greater than the cardinality $y$ of $\mathbb Z$,   $x>y$;  therefore you cannot have a subscript of $(a,d)$ to be $w$, $\forall w\in \mathbb R$, irrespective of what arithmetical and/or geometrical relations between elements $aRd$, by definition of $(a,d)\in \mathbb Z$  (unless of course you restrict your domain of $\mathbb R$ to mean some set $P$ which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb Z$, in which case $\exists some f(w) = (a,d)_w where f(P)\to \mathbb Z$ is one to one, and all $w\in P$)

Another way to understand is to simply consider each relation between $a$ and $d$ as $R_w$ so that $\forall x\in w$, $x$ is whatever sort of argument that $R$ is, for example in the case of your question argument $f(R) = x = a + nd$, and then ask the question whether the set of all $R_x$ $=A$ is a proper subset of the set of all $R_w$ $=B$, $A\subseteq B$? Of course you cannot do this because, for example you can show that there exists only 1 $w\in\mathbb R$ which can count every single $x\forall R$; take the sequence of the digits of $pi$ $\in w\in \mathbb R$ and let each digit be its own number $z\in \mathbb N$, since the function $g(z) = (a,d)_x$ is one to one, we know that there are no more $(a,d)_x$$\in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(g(z))$ is onto; therefore $w>x$